# Why aren't my HTML text boxes centered to show up the same on mobile devices and desktops?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my HTML text boxes are not centering. When I view them both on my desktop and on my mobile device, they show up differently. One is stretched while the other isn't centered. Ho can I make it so that my HTML code shows up the same in
both cases?

```html
<body>

  <div id="worked"></div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span></h1>
  <h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;"></h1>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
  <form class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;">
  <input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" />
  <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" />
  <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" 
         name="redirect" 
         type="hidden"
         value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" />
  <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" />
  <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" />
  <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." />
</div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
  <div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
    <div class="af-element">
      <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
      <div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;">
        <input id="awf_field-90534028" 
               class="text" 
               style="width: 450px; position: center;" 
               tabindex="500" 
               name="name" 
               type="text" 
               value="First Name..." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;">
      <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
      <div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;">
        <input id="awf_field-90534029" 
               class="text" 
               style="width: 450px; position: center;" 
               tabindex="500" 
               name="email" 
               type="text" 
               value="Best Email..." />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: center;">
      <input id="af-submit-image-604218668" 
             class="image" 
             style="background: none; max-width: 100%; width: 450px position: center;" 
             tabindex="502" 
             alt="Submit Form" 
             name="submit" 
             src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png"
             type="image" />
    </div>
    <div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
      <p><strong>I respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></strong></p>
      <div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
  </form>
  <!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->

</body>

<script>
  var handler = function() {
if (--sec < 0) {
  sec = 59;
  if (--min < 0) {
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
  }
}
var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
var min2 = min + "m";
var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
var sec2 = sec + "s";
var col = ":";
min1 = min1.fontcolor("red");
min2 = min2.fontcolor("red");
sec1 = sec1.fontcolor("red");
sec2 = sec2.fontcolor("red");
col = col.fontcolor("red");
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1 : min2) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1 : sec2);
  };
  var sec = 0;
  var min = 15;
  handler();
  setInterval(handler, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `position: center` in CSS. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control). Also, you have the text boxes in a div element with `style="text-align: left"`, so they're aligned... left.

Answer (score 1):

What text-box are you talking about?

If you are talking about the two input elements so why do you have on the wrapping div text-align: left? if you want it centered the containing element must be aligned to the center.

If you want the text inside the input to be centered you must put text-align: center in the input style, the position: center does not exist in css. (Example on "First Name" for text-align: center)

```html
<body>
  <div id="worked"></div>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #ff0000;"><strong>Offer Ends In:</strong></span>
  </h1>
  <h1 id="time" style="text-align: center;"></h1>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
  <form class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;">
  <input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" />
  <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" />
  <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" />
  <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" 
     name="redirect" 
     type="hidden"
     value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" />
  <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" />
  <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" />
  <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." />
</div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
  <div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
  <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
  <div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: center;">
    <input id="awf_field-90534028" 
           class="text" 
           style="width: 450px; text-align: center;" 
           tabindex="500" 
           name="name" 
           type="text" 
           value="First Name..." />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;">
  <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
  <div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: center;">
    <input id="awf_field-90534029" 
           class="text" 
           style="width: 450px; position: center;" 
           tabindex="500" 
           name="email" 
           type="text" 
           value="Best Email..." />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: center;">
  <input id="af-submit-image-604218668" 
         class="image" 
         style="background: none; max-width: 100%; width: 450px position: center;" 
         tabindex="502" 
         alt="Submit Form" 
         name="submit" 
         src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png"
         type="image" />
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
  <p><strong>I respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></strong></p>
  <div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
  </form>
  <!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
</body>

<script>
  var handler = function() {
if (--sec < 0) {
  sec = 59;
  if (--min < 0) {
    min = 0;
    sec = 0;
  }
}
var min1 = "0" + min + "m";
var min2 = min + "m";
var sec1 = "0" + sec + "s";
var sec2 = sec + "s";
var col = ":";
min1 = min1.fontcolor("red");
min2 = min2.fontcolor("red");
sec1 = sec1.fontcolor("red");
sec2 = sec2.fontcolor("red");
col = col.fontcolor("red");
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (min < 10 ? min1 : min2) + col + (sec < 10 ? sec1 : sec2);
  };
  var sec = 0;
  var min = 15;
  handler();
  setInterval(handler, 1000);

</script>
```